# Converting from CSS font size in pt to an Android equivalent

Tags: android, html, css, textview, typography

I have a line of CSS font information from the CSS font property, as shown:
"font": "bold 10pt Helvetica"

The specification for the property is here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp

I'm wondering how to convert the font size (10pt or the like) into a corresponding size in Android. I tried using:

```
TextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, 10);
```

But this oversizes the font, and I've found out that it seems like Android point values are difference then the web canvas or CSS element. Does anybody know the conversion for this or an equivalent unit sizing I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The size of a textview or basically any other view object on android usually have units in dp(device independent pixels), sp . You can try using the visual editor and setting the text sizes as you will see them preview on your screen.

Comment: I need a way to convert from CSS style font size (pt) to Android sizing (in sp). Guessing is unfortunately not an option for me. Any suggestions?